# Laptop booting up to strange characters

Tags: laptop, boot, windows-vista

I have a laptop running Windows Vista, and upon booting all I see are strange unreadable characters. I am not able to get past this screen—I can only access the BIOS and everything seems fine there.

[image: strange characters]

Can you please help!?

Comment: Can the computer boot into Safe Mode? Press and hold `F8` when the computer is starting, and see if you're able to go into safe mode. If so, your display drivers might be corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the BIOS works OK, it looks like your bootloader is corrupt.

Looks to me like it's meant to be a message, but possibly for a character set in another language, especially if it's centered on the the top of the screen.  You might have gotten bit by a virus that overwrote your bootloader.  (This could just be my imagination going wild - but I would say based on how there are several common pairs of characters through the string that it's a Chinese or other Asian language message - as those fonts are rendered in text mode using two characters side by side.)

Try following a guide such as [this one](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=556) to boot off of your original Windows DVD and run a couple commands to repair it.  If this is really a virus and it has done this, chances are it's trashed more of your hard drive other than the bootloader.